# Tracking detected objects in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, object-recognition, video-tracking, object-tracking

I'm recognizing objects on the Darknet using OpenCV. The image contains several objects of the same type.
I need to assign an ID for each detected object, but cv::Tracker and cv::legacy::MultipleTracker require an image to work. I can't send object coordinates to them.

Is there a way in OpenCV to track (assign an ID and follow it in a sequence of frames) already detected objects?

I have cv::Rect for each object in image. But i didn't find way to send it to cv::Tracker or cv::MultiTracker.

Comment: there are different things called "tracking". The one thing is to get objects (and time) as input and the tracking will try to identify which is the objects is the same in both images, just from their position changes. Have a look at Kalman-Filter, Hungarian Algorithm, Particle Filtering (Codensation) and similar for that thing. The other thing called tracking is to get objects+pixels once and pixels afterwards. The tracking will try to find similar image content in the new frames, which is assumed to be faster than detection.